# Are all Timeseries Arrays Vectors?

Tags: python, vector, finance, stock

If I have an array of daily stock prices, would it be considered a vector since it could drastically change in both magnitude and direction as more observations occur?

Comment: Please give an example of the data and your definition of a vector.

Comment: What definition of a vector are you using here?  If we're talking about `numpy`, a "vector" is technically any 1-D array (either horizontal or vertical).  The change in magnitude and direction sounds like a more scientific definition of what a vector would be.